# FDFs not working with Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, fdf

http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/dev/fdf.php

That results in a PDF with fields that have been populated in Firefox but in Google Chrome it doesn't do anything.  Assuming I'm not doing something wrong then my assumption would be that that means Chrome simply doesn't support FDFs?  And if not is there a work around?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the result of the #FDF functionality being an Adobe reader specific function. Chrome has its own built in pdf viewer and does not understand where to "find" the FDF file.

This guess is entirely based on the [following post to the adobe community forums](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3878224#3878224).

I am moving on to pdf_tk which does seem to work fine for merging server side... I hope someone comes up with a better answer soonish...

HTH,
-FT